# Camera isn't working properly

Tags: camera

So down below is the current 3D viewport of the project I'm working on:
[image]
[image]
As you can see, I have my camera selected and all I want to do is enter the camera view so that I can position it properly to face my car, but the problem is that when I enter the camera view, it's not working properly at all. Here's what I mean:

When I press 0 on my number pad, this comes:
[image] 
That's what it shows for some reason even though I clearly positioned the camera to face the car. Once I press 0, I noticed that the viewport goes down inside the car instead of going to the view of the camera for some reason.

Then when I pan away and zoom out from that view by using the middle mouse button then press CTRL + ALT + 0, something worse happens:
[image]
[image]
In the first pic, you can see that my camera is still in the same position where I placed it at and it hasn't moved to the position where I pressed CTRL + ALT + 0.
Then at the second pic, when I pressed the middle mouse button to pan around and see what happened, my car has suddenly moved to the position where I pressed CTRL + ALT + 0 at and I have no clue how that happened.

Can someone pls help me fix my camera? I feel like the car is acting as the camera but I'm not so sure. I'm using the latest version of Blender, 2.82.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, you may report it using link on the splash screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle on the top of an active camera is full yellow. The camera you've selected is not the active one, actually when you press <kbd>0</kbd> you switch to the current active one, and when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> you just move the active one to the current view. To make a camera active, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Then, next time, you can use <kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :)